# Are there any Part 135 (On-Demand Passenger Charter) companies out there that use Aviation Bio-Fuel?

Tags: commercial-aviation, fuel, fuel-systems, far-135, carbon-footprint

I was recently approached by a client asking if I can provide charters on environmentally conscious aircraft that run on Aviation Bio-Fuel.

Anyone have any insight on what is required for an aircraft to run on bio-fuel?

Who is implementing the use of Aviation Bio-Fuel in their fleet?

How do I find out which airports actually have Bio-Fueling capabilities?

Comment: I'm not sure biofuel is even available in larger quantities, it would have to be ordered probably weeks or months in advance, and I hope your clients are ok with paying way more than traditional charter costs. Nobody has implemented it yet, although some have done test flights, and it was approved in 2011.

Answer (score 3):

Biofuel has already been considered and tested on some aircrafts. [Here](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/10/business/global/10iht-green10.html?_r=1) you can find an article about tests.It states at least six of them

> At least six airlines, including KLM, Lufthansa and Finnair, have now
>   used biofuel on flights carrying passengers.

However there is still a long way to go.On wikipedia it says

> The sustainable aviation fuels certification and production pace seems
>   insufficient to meet the IATA target of halving the CO2 emissions by
>   2050

But airports do not supply bio-fuels for now since you need tons, even for one flight.

And for the list that used biofuel on their commercial flight you can check this [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation_biofuel) out. On that list i know KLM, interjet,Hainan offers charter flight. So it is safe to say those companies environmentally conscious, if you want.